# Magento PayPal Payments Advanced: Not tested code slipped in release?

Tags: php, magento, paypal

I'm setting up Magento installation (using bitnami magento image 1.7.0) and can't get PayPal payments to work. I've set up everything as shown in [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mw_9XoE-PEI), but after trying to complete order, in payment_payflow_advanced.log I see following:

> [result] => Array
>           (
>               [response_code] => -1
>               [response_reason_code] => 0
>               [response_reason_text] => Unable to read response, or response is empty
>           )

I've browsed through forums and tried this:
1) DNS issue - I've tried `wget https://payflowlink.paypal.com/` - it works.
2) Curl has SSL enabled

What else I could check?

**Update**: I've added url to zend exception, that throws message logged in log, so it tries to access `https://payflowpro.paypal.com:443/transaction`. If I'm trying to open this link in browser, I get 324net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE.

**Update 2**: I've also tried PayFlowLink method, the same issue.

**Update 3**: I’ve noticed something strange.

In

```
\magento\htdocs\app\code\core\Mage\Paypal\Model\Payflowlink.php
```

there’s a line:

```
const TRANSACTION_PAYFLOW_URL = 'https://payflowlink.paypal.com/';
```

Which I think should tell magento where to send data for secure id generation. Thing is, that this constant is not used anywhere in magento code, also this link isn’t used anywhere else, that's why I think it logs request to payflowpro, not payflowlink and I'm wondering if this code was tested by anybody.

**Update 4**:

In version 1.7.0.1 looks like same problem as mentioned in Update 3

I’m wondering if anybody had any success setting up PayPal Payments Advanced in Magento, if yes, which version of Magento was there?

[image: magento settings]
[image: magento settings]
[image: paypal settings]
[image: paypal settings]

[image: paypal status]

**Update 6**:
I've made a curl test like this:

```
<?php

   $ch = curl_init("https://www.google.com/");
   $fp = fopen("example_homepage.txt", "w");

   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);

   curl_exec($ch);
   curl_close($ch);
   fclose($fp);
 ?>
```

And it wrote file as expected, had no trouble with https.

**Update 7**:

```
Request log:

 [request] => Array
        (
            [user] => ****
            [vendor] => me****
            [partner] => PayPal
            [pwd] => ****
            [verbosity] => HIGH
            [tender] => C
            [cancelurl] => http://mydomain.com/index.php/paypal/payflow/cancelPayment
            [errorurl] => http://mydomain.com/index.php/paypal/payflow/returnUrl
            [silentpost] => TRUE
            [silentposturl] => http://mydomain.com/index.php/paypal/payflow/silentPost
            [returnurl] => http://mydomain.com/index.php/paypal/payflow/returnUrl
            [template] => minLayout
            [disablereceipt] => TRUE
            [cscrequired] => TRUE
            [cscedit] => TRUE
            [emailcustomer] => FALSE
            [urlmethod] => GET
            [createsecuretoken] => Y
            [securetokenid] => 7ebabf98872aee2ff84be75d1483e453
            [trxtype] => S
            [amt] => 150.00
            [currency] => USD
            [invnum] => 100000006
            [custref] => 100000006
            [ponum] => 39
            [firstname] => Gxxx
            [lastname] => Bxxx
            [street] => Vxxx
            [city] => Kxxx
            [state] => Lxxx
            [zip] => 4xxx
            [country] => LT
            [email] => gxxx@xxx.com
            [shiptofirstname] => Gxxx
            [shiptolastname] => Bxxx
            [shiptostreet] => Vxxx
            [shiptocity] => Kxxx
            [shiptostate] => Lxxx
            [shiptozip] => 4xxx
            [shiptocountry] => LT
            [user1] => 1
            [user2] => 48a9896a17493d6b97de838c4b40026d
        )

    [result] => Array
        (
            [response_code] => -1
            [response_reason_code] => 0
            [response_reason_text] => Unable to read response, or response is empty. Uri:https://payflowpro.paypal.com:443/transaction
        )

    [__pid] => 31628
```

As long as have no suggestions, that work, may be someone could suggest easiest way to ensure, that with paypal payments advanced account is everything ok?

Comment: A few questions:

Is this in production mode? or are you testing this via sandbox? Did you set Secure Token to On? Did you configure the correct URLs/configs on manager.paypal.com? If you can, please share information to your best knowledge. The last time I have successfully setup Paypal Payments Advanced was probably 1.5+, 1.6.2.0

Comment: I've updated with settings screenshots, I was trying production and test modes without success.

Comment: I've checked 1.6.2.0 source, it also does not use TRANSACTION_PAYFLOW_URL const anywhere.

Comment: Is your partner actually Paypal for your PayFlowPro account?  Do you actually have a valid PayFlowPro account?  This is a different service than regular Paypal accounts.

Comment: As I understand PayFlowPro and PayPal Payments Advanced are different services, I've updated question with PayPal service status. According to https://cms.paypal.com/cms_content/US/en_US/files/developer/PayflowGateway_Guide.pdf page 14, PayPal Payments Advanced are enabled.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Magento is known for setting variables/constants and never using them.

With that said look into `app/code/core/Mage/Paypal/Model/Payflowpro.php` look for the  `_postRequest()` method, I would add some debugging around the `$client` and `$result` objects.

Also below on the `catch (Exception $e)` you'll notice the source of your original error message, since this is the case your exception is occurring within the `Varien_Http_Client` :

```
    try {
       /**
        * we are sending request to payflow pro without url encoding
        * so we set up _urlEncodeBody flag to false
        */
        $response = $client->setUrlEncodeBody(false)->request();
    }
    catch (Exception $e) {
        $result->setResponseCode(-1) 
            ->setResponseReasonCode($e->getCode())
            ->setResponseReasonText($e->getMessage());

        $debugData['result'] = $result->getData();
        $this->_debug($debugData);
        throw $e;
    }
```

With the above code, your problem most likely is coming from Curl itself, or a mis-configuration on either magento's or the servers end.  I would validate Curl is installed and working properly via methods outside of Magento completely, for example:

- http://php.net/manual/en/curl.examples-basic.php

Before the `$response` in the try catch block, I would add a log (`mage::log`) or dump (`zend_debug::dump`) on the `$client` object to get more details on how the request is being formed and sent.

You should be able to find further info within `/lib/Varien/Http/Client.php` and `Adapter/Curl.php` by dumping or logging.

Feel free to post the results of any debugging mentioned above.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I'll try that, but as I've said I'm using bitnami magento image, so I'm pretty confident regarding php/curl configuration, so far I have quite solid impression about how it is configured.

Comment: I've updated question - tested curl with https link, it works ok. Regarding exception - Zend http client saves request in case of exception, I've added it to question too

Comment: Although your answer didn't provided exact solution - you were right - it was curl problem.

Answer (score 1):

So what I did, I took Payflow sample from here https://www.x.com/node/2749 and placed in magento directory.
I've ran it, and noticed, that although it didn't failed when getting secure token, it took exactly 1 minute to execute request, that brought idea, that it timeouts, so I've tried that on my pc and that took less than a second and generated secure id. 
So problem was, that curl.exec timeouts, question is why?

I've started putty and tried same request from example in link above and it gave me

> curl: (35) Unknown SSL protocol error in connection to payflowpro.paypal.com:443

Now it's something! 
I had similar issue many years ago, but it was so painful, that I still remembered solution that helped - so I've tried to pass another versions of SSL, and version 3 passed!

All I had to do is to add SSL version option to Varien Http Client and bum - everything works.

Comment: X.com is no longer active, can you explain what you did? Thanks

Comment: I'm sorry, that was long time ago and I touch Magento very occasionally.